# Why does my program crash when I change the targetSdkVersion?

Tags: android

I need to utilize a ActionBar  so I need to change the targetSdkVersion to 11.
It is currently targetSdkVersion="8".  **It works fine with targetSdkVersion="8"** , but when I change it to targetSdkVersion="11" it crashes.

The error originates at this line : **imageA= new  ImageAdapter(this,url);**

Error:

- 03-21 22:09:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(21824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ameba.api/com.ameba.api.Home}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

I've tried encapsulating almost every method in an AsyncTask<> , the errors are no longer thrown but the ImageAdapter() (never called) does not work when I do this.

Here is a snippet of the code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);      
    setContentView(R.layout.home); 


    title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);        
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.propGridView);
    thumbNail = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.propertyThumbnail);
    //thumbNail.setImageBitmap(bm); 
    gridView.setVerticalSpacing(3);
    gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(3);

    //checkHistory();

    ImageDownloader.Mode mode = ImageDownloader.Mode.CORRECT;        

    historyStack.pushValue(url);                                        // Push Value onto history stack
    Log.i("No history:",url+" "+historyStack.getStack().size());        //Debug
    imageA= new  ImageAdapter(this,url);     
    imageA.getImageDownloader().setMode(mode);                          //Set download mode to cache            
    gridView.setAdapter(imageA);                                        //Populate gridView with downloaded bitmap     
}  

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

//intialize variables
private final ImageDownloader imageDownloader ;
private int SIZE;
private List<Video> myVideos;
private Context mContext; 
private String xmlurl;
private Parser  parser = new Parser();


/*
 * Constructor
 * @params: Context
 * @params: XML url
 */
public ImageAdapter(Context c, String url){
    mContext = c;
    xmlurl = url;
    parser.runParser(xmlurl);    
    imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
 */
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ImageView view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view= new ImageView(mContext);
        view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(175,175));
        view.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

    }
    else{
        view = (ImageView)convertView;
    }
   Log.i("Assingning view","");
   imageDownloader.download(parser.getList().get(position).getThumbNail(),view);    
   return view;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
 */
public int getCount() {
    SIZE = parser.getCount();
    return SIZE;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
 */
public String getItem(int position) {
    return myVideos.get(position).toString();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
 */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public void setUrl(String url){
    xmlurl = url;
}

/*
 * getMethod
 */
public ImageDownloader getImageDownloader() {
    return imageDownloader;
}



  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the exception

```
Android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

It is telling you exactly what is wrong. You are trying to perform network activity (downloading your images) on the main UI thread. In previous versions of Android this was allowed without regard to device performance. Because downloading on the UI thread will severely affect the performance of your application this is discouraged and in later versions of Android will throw the error you see above.

Move downloading your images into a separate thread and this error will go away.

Comment: Yep I did that, and the error is no longer being thrown. However, the images are no longer appearing.

Comment: Take a look at some source code to do lazy image loading [HERE](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList). If you implement it you'll have a nice and quick plug n play image loader for your activity. It's pretty efficient as well. This will prevent you from having to handle callbacks when your downloads finish as well as managing your imageviews which I'd imagine is where you're having trouble and is causing your images to now show up

Comment: I implemented the lazy loader example. It works on the emulator but does not display the images on the device.

Comment: Are you sure you have good connection on the device? Do you have the internet permission specified in the manifest? Does your device have external storage?

Comment: The device is able to connect to the web no problem.  It does not has external storage(Media storage) as far as I can see. The internet permission is set as well.

Comment: The lazy loader will (should) check to see if there is external storage available. If not it should just use the internal storage. So, it should be saving the file no matter what. The only think I could think of is that you don't have the write_external_storage permission and its failing when trying to write ? and perhaps the emulator doesn't have external storage so its defaulting to saving on the internal storage (hence it working fine). Just a thought. Does Logcat show any warnings?

Comment: I think I see the problem java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/LazyList/129133212 (No such file or directory)

Comment: Use ADB or a file explorer on the device to see if the folder & file even exist.

Comment: I modified the FileCache class so it just sets : cacheDir=context.getCacheDir(); and it works now. I will put in some proper checks now. Thanks a lot man you are a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You should program the imageDownloader in threads or if you wanna run the code right now add in OnCreate:

```
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(
            new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().detectAll().permitNetwork().build());
```

this allow run your code, but isn't recommended.